# Replacing multiple chars in a string with one character in Python

Tags: python, list, replace, str-replace

I'm looking for a neat way to replace multiple occurrences of a particular character in a string with just one.

For example:
I would like to convert such string:

```
string = '1;AA;;1234567;;some text;;some text;;;some text;some text;;;;;;1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6;;;;;;;;;;;another text;;;;;;;;;;;;;'
```

to this:

```
string = '1;AA;1234567;some text;some text;some text;some text;1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6;another text;'
```

One of the approaches is to use list-based replacement, but it requires making quite an enormous list since the number of duplicates varies in subsequent data lines.

So something like this:

```
list = {';;':'';'.';;;'',';':'',';;;;':';',';;;;;':';'} #etc....
input = input.replace(list)
```

is not really a good idea.

Any suggestions on how should I proceed?

Regards,
J.

Comment: Try `string = re.sub(r";+", ";", string)`

Comment: Thank you, this is it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
import re
input_string = '1;AA;;1234567;;some text;;some text;;;some text;some text;;;;;;1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6;;;;;;;;;;;another text;;;;;;;;;;;;;'
print(re.sub(r";+", ";", input_string))
```

Comment: Thank you, it works fine!

Answer (score 1):

Using `split()`, list comprehension and `join()`

```
string = '1;AA;;1234567;;some text;;some text;;;some text;some text;;;;;;1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6;;;;;;;;;;;another text;;;;;;;;;;;;;'
x = string.split(';')    # returns a list with '' instead of the repeating ';'
x = [i for i in x if i]  # deletes the '' from the list
y = ';'.join(x)          # join back the list to a string separated by ';'
print(y)
```

Or

```
string = ';'.join([i for i in string.split(';') if i])
```

Comment: You don't need the `[]` inside the `.join`

Comment: And look the end of the result: The ";" is missing.

Comment: thanks for the feedback

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, but - as Timus wrote - ";" is being removed instead of reduced to one appearance.